# SVG polygon with point coordinates in percent

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon

I can use percent values in the coordinates of a rectangle in svg, but not in a polygon. Is there a workaround?

I mean, this is ok:

```css
svg {
  background: #ADF;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
}
rect {
  stroke: black;
  fill: #8FF;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="10%" y="10%" width="80%" height="70%"/>
</svg>
```

But this doesn't work:

```css
svg {
  background: #ADF;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px
}
polygon {
  stroke: black;
  fill: #8FF;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <polygon points="20%,10% 10%,90% 80%,90%"/>
</svg>
```

Chrome complains

> Error:  attribute points: Expected number, "20%,10% 10%,90%
>   80…".

Is there a way I can draw a filled polygon with percent coordinates?

Comment: I would like to mix pixel values that don't scale (e.g. stroke-width="1") with percent values, but I can only do this with rectangles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SVG coordinate system is defined by the `viewbox` of the SVG.

Define your viewbox as say `0 0 100 100` and translate the percentage points to numbers based on that viewbox.

Then the SVG will scale automatically.

**If you want to avoid stroke scaling...there's a CSS property for that too!**

```css
svg {
  background: #ADF;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px
}
polygon {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width:1;
  fill: #8FF;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox=" 0 0 100 100">
  <polygon points="20,10 10,90 80,90" />
</svg>
```